# iPad Pro Real Device is not listed in Katalon Studio devices

Tags: ui-automation, xcodebuild, ios-ui-automation, katalon-studio

I have setup the environment and also ran xcodebuild but when I try to see my attached iPad Pro on devices list, I don't see it. As suggested in troubleshoot site, the command prints device ID. I have iPad Pro with iOS 11.4.1. MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 I have latest Katalon Studio installed.

I setup mobile environment as per all the instructions but when I finally run this command "xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=' test" with udid replaced with my iPad udid, then I do not get "Listening to USB" when Test Cases Start running. Instead I get "Using singleton test manager". Because of this reason or may be another reason, Katalon is not listing my device name.
When I run following command, my device id is listed:
cd /Applications/Katalon\ Studio.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/resources/tools/imobiledevice 
idevice_id -l
I am attaching the screenshot which shows the messages displayed after running xcodebuild command

[image]